# Adding simple legend to plot in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a very simple plot.
I am using [this data](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/a.csv):

```
a <- read.table("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/a.csv", sep=',', header=TRUE)

plot(a$X25, type="l",col="red", ylim=c(0,100))
lines(a$X25.1, type="l", col="blue")
lines(a$X25.2, type="l", col="green")
lines(a$X25.3, type="l", col="brown")
```

Now I would like to add a simple legend that indicates which color is which variable.

I understand that I can use the `legend()` command, but my problem is that I don't know how to put colors next to the text in the legend.

What's the simplest command that would do this?

Comment: -1 See `?legend` and run the examples...

Comment: The dataset this question refers to is no longer available

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Take a look at `?legend` and try this:

```
legend('topright', names(a)[-1] , 
   lty=1, col=c('red', 'blue', 'green',' brown'), bty='n', cex=.75)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! one more question: is there any way to ensure that the legend remains readable when I resize the image? the x and y axes are flexible to resizing but the legend gets distorted

Comment: Maybe using `cex` argument is the key in this case.