# Adding legend to existing lines in a plot in r

Tags: r, regression, legend, lines

I'm trying to add a legend for my regression plot with several coloured lines.
What I've done is

```
plot(Leaves ~ Elevation)

plot(Elevation, Leaves, xlab="Elevation",ylab="Presence")

g=glm(Leaves~Elevation,family=binomial,data=Leaf)

curve(predict(g,data.frame(Elevation=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

I do this for every line and end up with up with a plot with several coloured lines and i know have to add a legend for the lines.

But i don´t know how to add some colour explanations figures to the legend, and all I've seen so far I have to start over again with doing the lines as well. Is there not an easy way to add colour explanation legends to already existing lines.

Comment: Is that what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883238/adding-simple-legend-to-plot-in-r

Comment: It´s a shame I could not load up a picture of the plot, it´would clarify what i´m after. I already now have to ad a legend but I don´t know have to ad symbols with different colour in the legend to explain witch of the different coloured lines is what.

Comment: So I already has three lines in different colours in the plot and need to show in the legend which  name and line has which colour in the plot.

Comment: Extend the example in TWL's link. Use the pch command to add the different symbols and col to add the different colours. Add them in the order that corresponds to the names in the legend, For example, legend('topright', legend= c("NameSet1","NameSet2") , pch=0:1, col=c('red', 'blue')). So the points corresponding to Nameset1 are red squares and for Nameset2, blue circles

Comment: Tank you both of you! It was really easy :)