# ScatterPlot of Cars example

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a scatterplot from `mtcars` of: `hp ~ mpg` and for each point (x,y)  show how many cylinders (`cyl`) by different colors. 
I tried to use the function `ScatterPlot` , but it's not recognized without adding the 'car' package.
So I tried :

```
plot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$hp , data=mtcars, xlab="HP", ylab="Hwy.MPG")
```

How can I add number of cylinders for each point of this graph? (with different colors)

Comment: Is this the `mtcars` dataset with different names? If not, where does this data come from?

Comment: yes it is. I just change the variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using `mtcars` from `datasets`.

The simplest way to add colour is to just add a `col`argument:

```
plot(mpg ~ hp , data=mtcars, col=cyl, xlab="HP", ylab="Hwy.MPG")
```

[image]

If you want custom colours, you can use the `palette`function:

```
palette(c("red", "blue", "green"))
plot(mpg ~ hp , data=mtcars, col=cyl, xlab="HP", ylab="Hwy.MPG")
```

[image]

Comment: great! and there is a way to show Map of the colors?

Comment: You can use the `legend`function.

Comment: thanks I read now ,   legend("topleft", "Cyl Map", legend)
but what should I insert in the last argument? just 'Cyl'?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14883238/1465387) will help you, but you can also use: `legend("topright", legend=unique(mtcars$cyl), col=palette(), pch=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in `lattice`  It's a little more "Oo-Lala", and fairly straightforward.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, groups = cyl, pch = 19,
       xlab = "HP", ylab = "Hwy.MPG", auto.key = list(columns = 3))
```

[image]

Comment: In the `xyplot` arguments, I would change `pch=19` to `par.settings=list(superpose.symbol=list(pch=19))`

Answer (score 2):

And to complete the picture, here's the ggplot example

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl)), size = 4)
```

[image]