# How to change the color spectrum pattern of fill() in ggplot2 bar chart?

Tags: ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

Hi.

I  have a ggplot2 script which I will show it at the end of my question and I have created it with the help of other friends [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613006/how-to-add-main-title-and-manipulating-axis-labels-in-ggplot2-in-rstudio?noredirect=1&lq=1).

but its color spectrum is not satisfying for me.

In my old "barplot()" script, I had a line that shows the different color spectrum for each bar -> "**col=c(fill = rainbow(25)),**" and this rainbow colors was different from the **color spectrum** of **ggplot(fill=legend)**. Is there any way to use that rainbow spectrum which **begins with red instead of ggplot2 spectrum that begins with orange, in my recent ggplot2 script?** 
if it is possible, please add the appropriate lines in my script or mention the scripts and the position that I have to insert them because I have tried several instances and they did not work for me & it seems that the please of each command has some effect on the whole program.

Thank you in advance

```
        dat <- data.frame(
  FunctionClass = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",     "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "Y", "Z"), levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "Y", "Z")),
  legend = c("A: RNA processing and modification", "B: Chromatin structure and dynamics", "C: Energy production and conversion", "D: Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning", "E: Amino acid transport and metabolism", "F: Nucleotide transport and metabolism", "G: Carbohydrate transport and metabolism", "H: Coenzyme transport and metabolism", "I: Lipid transport and metabolism", "J: Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis", "K: Transcription", "L: Replication, recombination and repair", "M: Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", "N: Cell motility", "O: Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones", "P: Inorganic ion transport and metabolism", "Q: Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism", "R: General function prediction only", "S: Function unknown", "T: Signal transduction mechanisms", "U: Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport", "V: Defense mechanisms", "W: Extracellular structures", "Y: Nuclear structure", "Z: Cytoskeleton"),
  Frequency=c(360,391,897,1558,1168,448,1030,536,732,1292,2221,2098,789,117,1744,732,437,5162,1251,2191,603,216,2,14,739)
)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=FunctionClass, y=Frequency, fill=legend))+
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="seashell")
p + guides (fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1))+
xlab("Factor Class")+
ggtitle("COG Function Classification of Consensus Sequences")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scale_fill_manual(values=rainbow(25))`

(it's not a good colour scale though)

Comment: Dear Baptiste, Hi and thank you as it works great for me. But why you have said: " it's not a good color scale though" and what scale you suggest to me? Thank you again.

Comment: Because no one can meaningfully distinguish 25 different colors in a single plot. The coloring here is just decoration and does not communicate anything about the data. Each color maps to one tick on your x-axis. So why not just rely on the axis labeling?

Comment: Hi and thank you. I now get the point and before your description I  thought @baptiste means that the "fill()" color spectrum is better than "rainbow()" colors. I think because some x-axis labels are **very long**, using this color legend has became popular.

Comment: i do think the rainbow/colorjet palette of colours is a bad choice. See [for example](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947308005549) or [this one](http://geog.uoregon.edu/datagraphics/EOS/Light-and-Bartlein_EOS2004.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for these interesting papers. How I can use "HCL-based" color instead of HSV-based rainbow in my script ?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to ignore this answer and your question. See `?scale_colour_hue` (the default scale)